# What is the output of an indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{A_i}(w)$ over some set $X=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$?

Tags: statistics

What is the output of an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) $\mathbb{1}_{A_i}(w)$ over some set $X=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$? And let $|A_i|=m<n$, so that every $A_i \subset X$.

Is it a set of n elements, a sequence of n elements, ... ?

Comment: Is $A_i \subset X$?

Comment: 1 if $w \in A_i$, 0 otherwise.

Comment: How do I know what $w$ is? Was thinking it's a single $w_i$. Or could it be a subset of $X$ that is of the size $|A_i|=m$? That is, the indicator function is evaluated in "chunks" of m-sized sets.

Comment: $w$ should be one of the $w_i$...

Comment: So then the output of the indicator function for $n$ ws is what? Specifically, in the case I'm evaluating this, the indicator function is also a random variable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable). I'm thinking it could be a set of 0s and 1s that is gotten by evaluating $\{\mathbb{1}_{A_i}(w_1),...,\mathbb{1}_{A_i}(w_n)\}$, but this is by definition of a set $\{0,1\}$, which doesn't make sense. Since the $\{\mathbb{1}_{A_i}(w_1),...,\mathbb{1}_{A_i}(w_n)\}$s could have $i!$ variations.

Comment: so in your case $w$ is a random variable?!

Answer (score 0):

$1_{A_i}(w)$ is a number (either 1 or 0). Definition:

$$1_{A_i}: X \to \{0,1\}: w \mapsto 1_{A_i}(w) := \begin{cases} 1 & ; w\in A_i \\ 0 &; w\notin A_i \end{cases}$$

Comment: But there are $n$ $w$s: $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$?

Comment: $w \in \{ w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n \}$ so $w$ is one of the $w_i$'s...

Comment: I'm thinking the indicator function checks for every $w \in X$? So it should produce some sort of n-length sequence, when it's evaluated "over" $X$.

Comment: The indicator function is a function with domain $X$ and target set $\{0,1\}$...

Comment: So what is the output, if the input is the whole X? How could it produce a single value out of n values?

Comment: Generally $1_{A_i}(X)=\{0,1\}$, the only exceptions being $1_{\varnothing}(X)=\{0\}$ and $1_{X}(X)=\{1\}$.

Comment: Addition: For each $A_i$ you get a different function $1_{A_i}$ which gives for each $w\in X$ a different value $1_{A_i}(w)$ ($1_{A_i}(w)$ is a number not a function). $1_{A_i}(X)$ is thus the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29) of $1_{A_i}$...

Comment: A subset of the codomain, i.e. $\{0,1\}$. And in fact: In general $1_{A_i}(X)$ is $\{0,1\}$ (unless $A_i=\emptyset$ or $A_i=X$)...